# Polymorphic UUAG attributes

Tags: haskell, uuagc

I'd like to define an attribute which is polymorphic. For a non-sensical example, suppose I want to `syn`thesize a list of any type (so in practice it can only be the empty list) :

```
ATTR Foo
  SYN lst : {[a]}
```

(a less non-sensical example could involve some typeclass constraint, or an `ST s (STRef s Something))` etc.)

The problem, of course, is that without telling UUAGC that `lst` is supposed to be polymorphic, it generates the following invalid Haskell code:

```
type T_Foo = ( ([a]))
data Inh_Foo = Inh_Foo {}
data Syn_Foo = Syn_Foo {lst_Syn_Foo :: ([a])}

sem_Foo :: Foo -> T_Foo
```

So how do I get UUAGC to instead generate something like

```
type T_Foo a = ( ([a]))
data Inh_Foo a = Inh_Foo {}
data Syn_Foo a = Syn_Foo {lst_Syn_Foo :: ([a])}

sem_Foo :: Foo -> T_Foo a
```

?

Comment: Figure 5 of [Merging Idiomatic Haskell with Attribute Grammars](https://svn.science.uu.nl/repos/project.ruler.papers/ag-haskell-paper/ag-haskell-lncs.pdf) implies I should be able to write `data Foo @a` but that syntax is rejected by UUAGC 0.9.52.